# How to read multiple line elements in Spark , where each record of log is starting with yyyy-MM-dd format and each record of log is multi-line?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, data-science, hadoop-partitioning

I have implemented below logic in scala so far for this :

```
val hadoopConf = new Configuration(sc.hadoopConfiguration); 
    //hadoopConf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "2016-")
    hadoopConf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "^([0-9]{4}.*)")

    val accessLogs = sc.newAPIHadoopFile("/user/root/sample.log", classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text], hadoopConf).map(x=>x._2.toString)
```

I want to put regex to recognize the if line started with date format then treat it as a new record else continue to add lines in old record.

But this is not working. If i am passing date manually then its working fine. Below is the same code like this i want to put the regex:

```
//hadoopConf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "2016-")
```

Please help on this.thanks in advance.

Here below is the sample format:

```
2016-12-23 07:00:09,693 [jetty-51 - /app/service] INFO  org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor S:METHOD_NAME=METHNAME : WebAppSessionId= : ChannelSessionId=web-xxx-xxx-xxx : ClientIp=xxxxxxx :  - Outbound Message

---------------------------
    ID: 1978
    Address: https://sample.domain.com/SampleService.xxx/basic
    Encoding: UTF-8
    Content-Type: text/xml
    Headers: {Accept=[*/*], SOAPAction=["WebDomain.Service/app"]}
    Payload: <soap:Envelope>
    </soap:Envelope>
2016-12-26 08:00:01,514 [jetty-1195 - /app/service/serviceName] ERROR com.testservices.cache.impl.ActiveSpaceCacheHandler S:METHOD_NAME=ServiceInquiryWithBands : WebAppSessionId= : ChannelSessionId=SERVICE : ClientIp=client-ip :  - ActiveSpaceCacheHandler:getServiceResponseFromCache(); exception: java.lang.Exception: getServiceResponseData: com.tibco.as.space.RuntimeASException: field key is not nullable and is missing in tuple for cachekey:Request.US
2016-12-26 08:00:01,624 [jetty-979 - /app/service/serviceName] ERROR com.testservices.cache.impl.ActiveSpaceCacheHandler S:METHOD_NAME=ServiceInquiryWithBands : WebAppSessionId= : ChannelSessionId=SERVICE : ClientIp=client-ip :  - ActiveSpaceCacheHandler:setServiceResponseInCache(); exception: com.test.as.space.RuntimeASException: field key is not nullable and is missing in tuple for cachekey
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I tried your regex with the given text and it seemed to match it correctly.

Comment: @Phasmid, thanks for your effort. I used (...*)*\s* at the end of the regex. So suppose if i have more than 1 record like above shared that it is selecting all of them. I need to put logic in my scala application that mapper function splits the per record rather than per line.

Comment: Is it apache spark related?

Comment: yes it is, i am trying to figure out logs data splitted by each record(starting with date time format) rather than per line and then my regex will test the matching pattern on that record.

Comment: Is the number of lines always the same for each log entry?  I'm guessing not because you are capturing a soap envelope? Also, are you interested in any of the lines following the line with the timestamp?

Comment: @AshishTyagi - do you want map function to ignore lines those are not starting with date format? - can you please add your expected output in your question?

Comment: @BigDataLearner - the initial issue got resloved by myself. Actually i have multiplelines of one single record in log and each record log is starting with date time format. So i want to pass data to map function per record.

Comment: For this my below code is working fine in spark-shell : val conf = new Configuration
 val rgx = "^(([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}))"//date regex
    conf.set("record.delimiter.regex", rgx)
    sc.newAPIHadoopFile("", classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text], conf)
 val logFile = sc.textFile("/user/root/sample.log") 
    val accessLogs = logFile.map(parseLogLine)

Comment: But when i am running it in Apache zeppelin its giving error org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration. Same code working fine in Spark-shell. Can you please help on this ?

Comment: @SHC i have updated now some more information above.

Comment: @Ashush, if you have found a solution for your original problem, you could also create an answer post stating how you fixed it.  If you now have a different question, it would probably be best to create a new question with a different title.

Comment: @SHC issue is still the same that i want to retrieve the data from the logs not per line wise rather per record-wise. However, i tried some solutions and make the technicality of this question as accurate as possible.

Comment: I'm still not clear what the question is.  Is it the NotSerializableException?

Comment: @SHC it is not about the exception, as i mentioned im not able to retrieve the records from the logs according to my requirement. Okay, do you the know the logic to parse my given logs in a way that each record starting with 2016-12-26 date should be treated as one record but each record may have multi-line in itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get it working with a regex.  The best I could do was `hadoopConf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "\n20")` which may work for you if you don't have those characters in the middle of a log entry.  This approach will also and give you future-proofing, supporting dates up to 2099

If you need a regex, you could try http://dronamk.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/regex-custom-input-format-for-hadoop.html

My code:

```scala
// Create some dummy data
val s = """2016-12-23 07:00:09,693 [jetty-51 - /app/service] INFO  org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor S:METHOD_NAME=METHNAME : WebAppSessionId= : ChannelSessionId=web-xxx-xxx-xxx : ClientIp=xxxxxxx :  - Outbound Message
          |---------------------------
          |    ID: 1978
          |    Address: https://sample.domain.com/SampleService.xxx/basic
          |    Encoding: UTF-8
          |    Content-Type: text/xml
          |    Headers: {Accept=[*/*], SOAPAction=["WebDomain.Service/app"]}
          |    Payload: <soap:Envelope>
          |    </soap:Envelope>
          |2016-12-26 08:00:01,514 [jetty-1195 - /app/service/serviceName] ERROR com.testservices.cache.impl.ActiveSpaceCacheHandler S:METHOD_NAME=ServiceInquiryWithBands : WebAppSessionId= : ChannelSessionId=SERVICE : ClientIp=client-ip :  - ActiveSpaceCacheHandler:getServiceResponseFromCache(); exception: java.lang.Exception: getServiceResponseData: com.tibco.as.space.RuntimeASException: field key is not nullable and is missing in tuple for cachekey:Request.US
          |2016-12-26 08:00:01,624 [jetty-979 - /app/service/serviceName] ERROR com.testservices.cache.impl.ActiveSpaceCacheHandler S:METHOD_NAME=ServiceInquiryWithBands : WebAppSessionId= : ChannelSessionId=SERVICE : ClientIp=client-ip :  - ActiveSpaceCacheHandler:setServiceResponseInCache(); exception: com.test.as.space.RuntimeASException: field key is not nullable and is missing in tuple for cachekey
""".stripMargin

import java.io._
val pw = new PrintWriter(new File("log.txt"))
pw.write(s)
pw.close

// Now process the data
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}

val conf = sc.getConf
sc.stop()
conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable]))
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val hadoopConf = new Configuration(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
hadoopConf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter", "\n20")

val accessLogs = sc.newAPIHadoopFile("log.txt", classOf[TextInputFormat], classOf[LongWritable], classOf[Text], hadoopConf)
accessLogs.map(x => x._2.toString).zipWithIndex().collect().foreach(println)
```

Note that I'm using zipWithIndex just for debugging purposes.  The output is:

```
    (2016-12-23 07:00:09,693 [jetty-51 - /app/service] INFO  org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor S:METHOD_NAME=METHNAME : WebAppSessionId= : ChannelSessionId=web-xxx-xxx-xxx : ClientIp=xxxxxxx :  - Outbound Message
    ---------------------------
        ID: 1978
        Address: https://sample.domain.com/SampleService.xxx/basic
        Encoding: UTF-8
        Content-Type: text/xml
        Headers: {Accept=[*/*], SOAPAction=["WebDomain.Service/app"]}
        Payload: 
        ,0)
    (16-12-26 08:00:01,514 [jetty-1195 - /app/service/serviceName] ERROR com.testservices.cache.impl.ActiveSpaceCacheHandler S:METHOD_NAME=ServiceInquiryWithBands : WebAppSessionId= : ChannelSessionId=SERVICE : ClientIp=client-ip :  - ActiveSpaceCacheHandler:getServiceResponseFromCache(); exception: java.lang.Exception: getServiceResponseData: com.tibco.as.space.RuntimeASException: field key is not nullable and is missing in tuple for cachekey:Request.US,1)
    (16-12-26 08:00:01,624 [jetty-979 - /app/service/serviceName] ERROR com.testservices.cache.impl.ActiveSpaceCacheHandler S:METHOD_NAME=ServiceInquiryWithBands : WebAppSessionId= : ChannelSessionId=SERVICE : ClientIp=client-ip :  - ActiveSpaceCacheHandler:setServiceResponseInCache(); exception: com.test.as.space.RuntimeASException: field key is not nullable and is missing in tuple for cachekey
    ,2)
```

Note the index is the second field in the output.

I ran this code on an [IBM Datascience Exerience](http://datascience.ibm.com/) notebook running Scala 2.10 and Spark 1.6

Comment: thanks for your help, just for now i also used the similar approach. I will look into your shared regex example :)